# Efficient algorithm to find the Minimum Number of independent sets of rectangles given as input a set n of intersected rectangles?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, intersection, rectangles

Input is a set of n (n > 10,000) rectangles.
Output should be the minimum number of independent (non-intersecting) sets of rectangles. That is, the minimum possible number of sets where each and every set has a group of non-intersecting rectangles.

As the input is very large, what is the most efficient algorithm to solve this type of problem.
  [For example: The attached photo describes my problem well with both the upper part as an input and the lower part as the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2M4v.png)

Edit:
Yes, 1 can be considered as the minimum number if and only if this single output set will not contain any intersecting rectangles.

I tried using Brute Force and pick each rectangle and loop through all the others. It actually worked but unfortunately the time complexity is horrible for large input and it may last for more than five minutes!

I searched for the problem and I found an algorithm (by Chalermsook and named as MISR) but I didn't understand its approach or more clearly, I needed an example using this approach for better explanation.

Comment: it's an interesting problem, but with little effort on your part, we can't help much.

Comment: That is a really hard problem you have there. There are going to be multiple valid solutions for sure. "The best" solution would probably require you to search the entire solution space, which is obviously unfeasible. If you are happy with any good solution instead of the best one, i would take a look at genetic algorithms. They tend to work well for large optimization problems like that and will likely be able to seperate your rectangles, provided that you can come up with a descent optimization objective.

Comment: Does 1 count as a minimum? 1 would fit very nicely. If not, try graph coloring with DP.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If rectangles can be arbitrarily oriented, then it's not generally possible to cover the resulting shape with non-intersecting rectangles. If they are all oriented in one direction (that is, it is possible to introduce two perpendicular axes so that each side of each rectangle is parallel to one axis or the other) then the resulting shape can be covered by exactly one set of non-intersecting rectangles.

Comment: I am not sure with 10k rectangle DP is available. I am not sure coloring or max clique cover (which are likely to be the same) is even affordable. Probably best is to allow an approximation...

Comment: I added more details in the question.

Comment: Are all rectangles describable by "min x, max x, min y, max y" (in other words, no diagonal lines)?

Comment: No diagonal lines, as I mentioned above all the rectangles are iso-oriented which means that they are all parallel to the axes.

Comment: @ShehabHosny I'm pretty sure this is NP-hard since it sound a lot like finding Chromatic number of a graph. Chromatic number approximation can be found in `O(n (log n)^−3(log log n)^2)`.

Comment: @Yonlif well yeah it is NP-hard. However I think that it might be implemented in O(log log n) using the Maximum Independent Set of Rectangles (MISR) algorithm but unfortunately I didn't get the steps of this algorithm.

Comment: you have not specified: is __approximation__ allowed. in MISR they directly precise it is an approximation in abstract. If you don't allow approximation, then forget MISR and probably forget a computable solution as of nowadays tools

Comment: @user753642 Well this is already a NP-hard problem. So only approximation results are computed, right?